# Str_Replace with Array Uppercase and numbers (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

I have a simple code but i cant do it works fine.

```
$String = 'abc123ABC';

$Replace_From = array("a","b","c","1","2","3","A","B","C");
$Replace_To   = array("A","B","C","a","b","c","1","2","3");

$NewString = str_replace($Replace_From, $Replace_To, $String);
echo $NewString;
```

- The correct result its: ABCabc123
- But my code return this result: 123abc123 !

Thanks you for your help!

Comment: Use [strtr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) instead; and understand the difference in how they work

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace` will replace all occurrences of the letter, so if we split the code in 2 we could understand more what happens:

```
<?php
$String = 'abc123ABC';

$Replace_From = array("a","b","c","1","2","3");
$Replace_To   = array("A","B","C","a","b","c");

$FirstString = str_replace($Replace_From, $Replace_To, $String);
echo $FirstString . '<br>';

$Replace_From = array("A","B","C");
$Replace_To   = array("1","2","3");

$SecondString = str_replace($Replace_From, $Replace_To, $FirstString);
echo $SecondString;
```

`$FirstString = 'ABCabcABC'` So `'A'` will be replaced by `1` two times and so for `'B'` and so for `'C'`.